# Laravel retrieve json column to balde

Tags: php, laravel

i have table contian 3 column, id + slug + name... And name column is a json column  and data stored like that

```
Id: 1
Slug: test
Name: {en:test;ar:تجربه}
```

now in balde i just want to show name.en only not {en:test;ar:تجربه}

Answer (score 1):

اهلا.

You have to decode the JSON string.

Example: `{{ json_decode($data->name)['en'] }}`

---

Though it is better to have a getter on your Model, e.g:

Model.php:

```
public function getJsonNameAttribute()
{
    return json_decode($data->name);
}
```

In your view:

`{{ $data->json_name['en'] }}`

---

Use @Manvir Singh's answer. It is better.

Comment: Cannot use objext of type stdclass as array

Comment: Hala, fene adifk we aklmk fc!

Comment: @KareemNourEmam Use Manvir's answer. It's better!

Answer (score 0):

Uaing json_decode is not a good idea, in Model file you can cast your column like this

`public $casts = [
'json_column' => 'object'
]`

Now your json column will be treated as object and you can access

`$data->json_column->en`